# Put section and page numbers in the margin with KOMA-Script

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, koma-script, page-numbering

Using the `scrartcl` document class, I would like to put the section number into the page margin, as is seen for example in the famous `l2tabu` document. That should be easily possible with KOMA-Script, but I can not find how.

Also, how can the same be done with page numbers, as is done for example in the good old `LaTeX Companion`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

With KOMA-Script version 3.19a or newer you simple have to redefine `\sectionlinesformat` to get the desired result:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2015/10/03]

\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{#3}#4%
}

\usepackage[headwidth=textwithmarginpar]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer**

Since [KOMA-Script version 3.17](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) (current version on CTAN) you have to redefine the commands `\sectionformat`, `\subsectionformat` etc. instead `\othersectionlevelsformat`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2015/04/23]
\renewcommand\sectionformat{\makebox[0pt][r]{\thesection\autodot\enskip}}
\renewcommand\subsectionformat{\makebox[0pt][r]{\thesubsection\autodot\enskip}}
\renewcommand\subsubsectionformat{\makebox[0pt][r]{\thesubsubsection\autodot\enskip}}

\usepackage[headwidth=textwithmarginpar]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The source code of l2tabu is available [on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu). There you can read it:

```
\renewcommand*{\othersectionlevelsformat}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\csname the#1\endcsname\autodot\enskip}}
```

The section number is put into a box of width 0, right aligned. So it runs into the left margin.

Comment: I found the command for setting the pagenumber in the margin. `\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}` Want to add it to your answer?

Comment: The definition is flawed: `\othersectionlevelsformat` has *three* arguments. The KOMA-Script documentation (p. 109 of a current version) suggests `\renewcommand*\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{\makebox[0pt][r]{#3\autodot\enskip}}`